# $R$ and $S$ are relations, prove about $S\setminus R$

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

1. If $R$ and $S$ are reflexive then $S\setminus R$ is reflexive.
2. If $R$ and $S$ are symmetric then $S\setminus R$ is symmetric.
3. If $R$ and $S$ are transitive then $S\setminus R$ is transitive.

and I would also like to ask about the empty group, what can we say about it being reflexive, symmetric, transitive?

Comment: One way to think about this is to realize every element of $S \backslash R$ comes from an element of $S$, and in some sense $R$ is closed under reflection, symmetry and transitivity so everything that happens in $S$ but not in $R$ stays in $S$ but not in $R$. See if you can formalize this!

Comment: Consider the set $X=\{0,1\}$, let $S=X^2$ and $R=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$. Then $S\setminus R = \{(0,1),(1,0)\}$. Is it reflexive?

Comment: Consider $X=\{0,1,2\}$, $S=X^2$ and $R=\{(0,2)\}$. They're both transitive, but $R\setminus S$ isn't, right?